# OS X: Elasticsearch+Logstash+Kibana with Apache 2.4 (mod_proxy_http) from Homebrew

Tags: macos, apache-http-server, webserver, httpd, http-proxy

Trying to setup Elasticsearch+Logstash+Kibana with Apache 2.4.

-- Successfully installed:

```
brew install elasticsearch logstash httpd24
```

-- Enabled virtual hosts module in **/usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4/httpd.conf:**

```
# Virtual hosts
Include /usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

and

```
LoadModule vhost_alias_module libexec/mod_vhost_alias.so
```

-- Created virtual host in **/usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf**:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName kibana4.serv
    ServerAlias www.kibana4.serv
    DocumentRoot /usr/local/var/www/kibana-4.0.2-darwin-x64/src/public
    <Directory /usr/local/var/www/kibana-4.0.2-darwin-x64/src/public>
        Require all granted
        Allow from all
        Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

-- Created new config for ELK **/usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4/other/elk.conf**:

```
LoadModule proxy_http_module /usr/local/opt/httpd24/libexec/mod_proxy_http.so

<Location /elasticsearch>
    ProxyPass http://localhost:9200/
    ProxyPassReverse /
    SSLRequireSSL
</Location>

<Location /kibana/>
    ProxyPass http://localhost:5601/
    ProxyPassReverse /
    SSLRequireSSL
</Location>
```

-- Included newly created config **elk.conf** to **/usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4/httpd.conf**:

```
Include /usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4/other/*.conf
```

BUT when I try to restart apache getting:

```
$ /usr/local/opt/httpd24/bin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
httpd: Syntax error on line 523 of /usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4/httpd.conf: 
Syntax error on line 1 of /usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4/other/elk.conf: 
Cannot load /usr/local/opt/httpd24/libexec/mod_proxy_http.so into server:
dlopen(/usr/local/opt/httpd24/libexec/mod_proxy_http.so, 10): 
Symbol not found: _ap_proxy_cookie_reverse_map\n  
Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/httpd24/libexec/mod_proxy_http.so\n  
Expected in: flat namespace\n in /usr/local/opt/httpd24/libexec/mod_proxy_http.so
```

What's the problem loading mod_proxy_http.so? The path to the module is correct...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've uncommented in httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule proxy_module libexec/mod_proxy.so
```

Comment: Your post needs to be expanded. A good [answer](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) includes specific instructions (not just links to them) and an explanation as to how or why the answer addresses the OPs question.  Please edit your post to add detail explaining how your solution addresses the OPs question.